# FreeBSD file group write permissions

Tags: user-accounts, file-permissions, freebsd

I have created a dummy file just to test out group permissions.

```
touch /path/test.txt
chown user1:txtwriter /path/test.txt
chmod 664 /path/test.txt && ls -la
```

returns:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 user1  txtwriter         0 Mar 23 14:59 test.txt
```

and with `user2` which is added to `txtwriter` group:

```
[user2@localhost (/path)]: echo blah > test.txt 
-bash: test.txt: Permission denied
```

How can I fix the permissions so all of the users added to the group can modify the file ?

Comment: Are you sure the group change has permeated to the current shell? Try the command `groups` with user2 to see if the group is listed. If not, run `newgrp txtwriter` in the current terminal, then try writing to the file again. If this was the problem, look up the definition of "login shell".

Comment: the group is listed

Comment: It seems to be working fine after logout and login again.